# how to enter an input to gets function via script in ruby

Tags: ruby

Whenever `gets` is called, is there any way to enter input via script itself, instead of entering manually in windows?

For example:

```
puts "enter your choice"
ch=gets                           
puts ch
```

In the above script when `gets` is called, is there any command to enter input to that via a script in windows?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the same program or another one?

Answer (score 1):

1) If you want to provide external input to STDIN when invoking your script

Let's say your gets command is inside a file named prog.rb. If you'd like to provide some fixed input to STDIN when running prog.rb, you could run it using a pipe from the command line:

```
echo "My input to gets" | ruby prog.rb
```

This will output

```
enter your choice
My input to gets
```

in the shell without requiring manual intervention.

2) An example for feeding STDIN from within the same script:

```
class MyIO
  def gets
    "1\n"
  end
end

$stdin = MyIO.new
puts "enter your choice"
ch=gets                           
puts ch # => 1
```

Comment: am working on windows, so i have a requirement like, when am running the ruby script after executing few steps it will ask to enter choice,

Comment: sorry the above comment is incomplete,so am writting here. Am working on windows, so i have a requirement like, when am running the ruby script after executing few steps it will ask to enter choice, ex: puts "enter your choice"                          choice=gets,                                                      so at choice=gets line the script will ask for the user to enter the choice, which I want to enter value "1" all the time via script itself, without asking user. I want to provide this input when the script is already running, via some variable through the script.

Comment: @madhu: Windows would probably require MyIO#gets to return "1\r\n". I can't confirm this, I have no Windows machine around right now.

Answer (score 1):

The [`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001404) function simply reads from `$stdin` so all you have to do is open a new [`File`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html) or [`StringIO`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/classes/StringIO.html) for reading and then assign it to `$stdin`.

For example, if you have a file called `pancakes.txt` and you do this:

```
$stdin = File.new('pancakes.txt', 'r')
puts gets
```

Then you'll see the first line of `pancakes.txt` on the standard output.

Comment: am working on windows, so i have a requirement like, when am running the ruby script after executing few steps it will ask to enter choice, ex: puts "enter your choice"                          choice=gets,                                                      so at choice=gets line the script will ask for the user to enter the choice, which I want to enter value "1" all the time via script itself, without asking user. I want to provide this input when the script is already running, via some variable through the script.

Comment: @madhu: Then instantiate a StringIO with your desired responses (separated by newlines) and assign that to `$stdin`. Then `gets` will read from your string instead of asking the user.